# Load retina (high quality) images programmatically (on buttons)

Tags: ios

I have a problem that I just haven't been able to figure out. I have an app done that will take a picture from the front and one from the back camera, then merge them together.

The name of the app is **GroupCam**

However I have an issue in where my UIButtons will not be loaded as retina images from the start. If i set them as @2x on the interface builder they do appear in high quality but once I reload them programmatically the low versions will appear instead.

This is due to the fact that, after a picture is taken and the screen changes the button images change, but when the user presses the back button the camera icons will look horrible (because the low quality versions are being loaded).

Please check the following pictures:

**First Screen:**　Only the upper right button appears distorted because I am checking the value of the camera flash and "loading" the corresponding image programatically.

[image: First Screen]

**Second Screen:**　The user has moved to another screen and came back to the first one, all buttons were reloaded and they now all look distorted.

[image: Second Screen]

Why is this happening?

Edit:

This is how I load the images.

```
[self.flashButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flashOff"] 
                          forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

I read somewhere on the internet that doing this will automatically load the most suitable version of the image.

I also tried this but the result is the same:

```
[self.takeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"takePhoto.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: I've had great results using normal and retina images in an app. So what I'd suggest you do is select the normal resolution of these images, and not include them in your project (via the 3rd rightmost pane - just unselect the checkbox). Now your app ONLY has retina images. Well, if things go bad, then something in your app screwed up. There is some issue with [UIImage imageNamed:foo.png]. If you change that image, all subsequent users of that image get the modified image. Re-read UIImage imageNamed:

Comment: So I just re-read you question, and I just saw this statement: "If i set them as "@2x" on the interface builder". So, in IB, you have entered their names as "takePhoto@2x.png", and that works. So the ONLY thing I can think of that your problem might be is the format of "@2x". Are you SURE you have properly named those images - "name@2x.png", NOT &2x.png etc. It just seems like iOS does not see the hi rez files and that is the ONLY reason I can think of that would explain it. So try removing the "@2x" in IB, and see what happens. I'll bet you get all low rez all the time then.

Comment: yes they are formatted and named correctly. The images will be loaded in HD perfectly fine by themselves, the only problem is when i load them programatically. iOS decides to load the low definition one.

Comment: The names you use are as above in the example, right? No "iPhone" or "iPad" suffix? I just looked at the Resource Programming Guide again for inspiration on this. The only other thing I could see was that the  deployment target has to be iOS 4 or newer. If this happened to me, I would create a new test project and add the images in a single view using imageNamed, just to see if its my system or my app. You could have some internal damage that is causing this. This @2x has just worked perfectly for me.

Comment: Can you attach the button image files (both resolutions), and the filenames, to your question?

Comment: Exactly - in terminal do a ls on all image files and add to your question. The case issue mentioned below by RAZ could be the problem. Also, someone else just reported the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/11665407/96716

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your app is taking a picture from the front camera and one from the back camera and merging them together, then the device requires a front facing camera. All iOS devices which have front facing cameras also have retina display's (so long as your not developing for the iPad 2, but that's a different story) so you shouldn't really have to have normal images at all, so all your images should be retina images. If there are no normal images, then this issue shouldn't happen at all. Make a backup copy, and try deleting all the normal images, and then try. Because your using the UIImage imageNamed:@"ImageName", like you said, should automatically select the image! Good Luck!

Comment: I was kinda hoping to find the reason why this is happening but this does seem to be a solution.

Comment: @LuisOscar Sorry, that was my best guess :( Try reporting a bug at bugreport.apple.com.

Answer (score 4):

First off, its probably worth verifying that the low-res versions are actually being displayed. I had jumped to a similar assumption recently, swapped out the low-res version of the image with something different, and confirmed that the hi-res version was actually still being displayed, but was being distorted.

My actual problem, I had set

`<uibutton_superview>.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;`

If any of the buttons ancestors have this set, it could likely be your problem.

Answer (score 3):

The case of the filenames of the images does not matter on the simulator, but does on the device.

Use all consistent case.  Image.png and image@2x.png are recognized and will work together in simulator but not on device.  use image.png and image@2x.png.  Or you can also use .jpg as long as case is matching.