# iOS Retina images not being used

Tags: ios, xcode

I've read and searched and still I don't have a solution.

Here goes:
I'm building a universal app and need to display an image in a UIImageView.
And guess what - Xcode keeps ignoring my @2x-images.

I've tried "myImage.png" and "myImage" - no @2x being displayed.
I've tried naming the files with "~ipad" etc., all the tips here...

Only when I hardcode "myImage@2x" Xcode will use the large version. Same thing in simulator and on the device.

Does anyone have another clue? Could it be because I didn't check "Targeted for iPad" when creating a new file?

Thank you for any help you can provide!

EDIT:
Xcode 4.3.3, iOS 5.1

Comment: How have you named the image files?

Comment: self.theImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];

Comment: currently I have only "myImage~ipad.png" and "myImage@2x~ipad.png" in my repository

Comment: There is another thread where someone is having the very same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10782997/96716 The best suggestion on that thread is to be 100% sure that the case of all letters in the two files is the same - wrong case and it won't get the retina image. You could also try to remove the "~ipad" but I seriously doubt that will make any difference (unless your problem is on the iPhone :-) )

Comment: @David H - thanks for the hint; but still no change here :/

Comment: Note that as a paid developer, you get two "incidents" with Apple's DTS - techical services. Email your problem to dts@apple.com along with your registered name, report this issue, and you can get an Apple engineer there to help you (takes a few days). When you find the answer pls update this post.

Comment: This thing is driving me nuts too! Two other suggestions - in your code where you get the image using imageNamed:, just after you get it then NSLog(@"ImageScale=%f screenScale=%f", image.scale, [UIScreen mainScreen].scale); They both should be 1.0, ESPECIALLY the second number!

Comment: Another idea - if the first number is 0 and the second 1, then manually try to get the second image imageNamed:myImage@2x.png and see if that image is returned with a scale of 2.